# Symfony profiler toolbar stuck on "Loading..."

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I just started a project on Symfony 6.3 and started imported some code from another project, when I realized that the Symfony profiler toolbar was stuck on "Loading..." with an "Attempt" counter going up.

No error seems to be showing, so I wonder how I can debug that. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to look at your browser's developer tools and check for any failing or pending XHR requests. Don't forget to dive into Symfony's logs (var/log directory) and see if there are any errors or warnings popping up there. And while you're at it, also peek at your browser's console for any JavaScript errors that could be getting in the way of the toolbar loading.